# Which indeces should I set in my database

Tags: mysql, database, database-indexes

I am writing an application to enter some test results.
The testers test about 40 releases per week with every release having 50 test results. That means per week 40x50 = 2000 results per week. Per month it will be about 10.000 test results. So as you see my database table testResults will grow very fast.

So now I am thinking of defining some indeces. A test result has a foreign key to testcase and to release it belongs to.

Thats why I am thinking to have 2 indeces. One on testcase_id and one to release_name(id in release table) . The reason is if someone wants to get test results for a specific testcase or for a specific release then it would take too long to search the whole results table which is ordered just by result_id  and I imagine after just one year there will be more than 100.000 entries, my application would be slowed down extremely...

But will be inserting a test result be also slowed down ? Every day a lot of test results will be added to my results table. Would that make it very slow now if always my 2 indeces need to be updated all the time ?

What I just saw in my database MySQL.
Foreign keys in MySQL automatically create an index on the table. why is that??

Comment: The indexes sounds like a good plan. I really wouldn't worry about your data size and inserts though as this really isn't much data at all. Even after a couple of years you are still in excel-sized data which mysql with proper indexing should handle very quickly.

Comment: but you imagine why MySql creates for every foreign key an index ?? I mean index is for speeding up performace, but if I do not need foreign key very often it is a waste of memory.

Comment: 100,000 isn't really a lot of data to be honest. MySQL should handle it fine. You can always archive older rows if it really does become a problem.

Comment: Indexes on foreign keys is good practice in Mysql. It even suggests it in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Indexes on any column that you plan to filter on is also good practice. Obviously the indexes have overhead when you `insert`, `update`, or `delete` but if you plan to perform `select` often then that overhead will be overtaken by your much much much faster select statements. Ultimately though your volume is very small so I wouldn't sweat this one. Put indexes in place like you plan and it should perform nicely.

Comment: Let's see the queries, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  From those, we can advise on what indexes would be useful.